# Nordic Semi Conductor Advertisement from nrf528040

Tags: installation, bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I am trying to broadcast an advertisement packet from a Nordic board nrf52840.

I have downloaded the latest nordic sdk and am loading the ble beacon example to the device. However, using nrf connect I can not see any advertisement being broadcast. I wish to know where my setup is wrong. The PCA is 10056. At the moment I just want to broadcast the device's name and see it. I am using sdk version 16.0.

Is there a decent setup guide anywhere as I tried to follow : https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/nordic/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-advertising-a-beginners-tutorial

But I never go an advertisement out from my device.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code at all? You have a dev kit, so you can use the built-in debugger and step through the code to see if it is failing anywhere. Do you know if the code is running at all? Did you load a softdevice on the board?

Comment: I have fixed this issue by creating an advertising mod function. This then advertises changes I make.